Javascript callback for when a child window is closed in Chrome
We've a simple popup window that opens to a shop.app checkout page, and we're trying to hook into when a user has navigated away from there/closed the window, to then query the api and update information in their profile, if the checkout was successful.
I've tried a few methods, but a lot of this seems to be old, old javascript that doesn't seem to work "right" any more?  Most topics on this are 10+ years old on here.
    const events = [
        "afterprint",
        "beforeprint",
        "beforeunload",
        "gamepadconnected",
        "gamepaddisconnected",
        "hashchange",
        "languagechange",
        "message",
        "messageerror",
        "offline",
        "online",
        "pagehide",
        "pageshow",
        "popstate",
        "rejectionhandled",
        "storage",
        "unhandledrejection",
        "unload"
      ]

    let proxy = window.open(
      buyUrl,
      "child",
      "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,width=430,height=220,left=500,top=100"
    )
    const listener = (title: string) => (event: unknown) => {
      console.log(title, event)
    }

    if (proxy) {
      events.forEach((eventType) => {
        proxy.addEventListener(eventType, listener(eventType))
      })
      proxy.onbeforeunload = listener("rawbeforeunload")
      proxy.onmessage = listener("rawmessage")
      proxy.onclose = listener("rawclosed")
    }

I got the list of events above from the keys of the WindowEventHandlersEventMap interface, just to see if I wasn't hooking into the right one.  Only 2 events are triggered, pagehide and unload, but both of those basically happen at the very same time, and only at the very start of the window's lifecycle, when the page is rendered.
I'd mainly just like to know when that window is closed from a callback, but obviously none of the above is working right for what I want.

I suggest webworkers onmessage events parent-iframe/popup ...

If "buyurl" is not from the same origin as the script then the only "old" way I can imagine is to wrap the "buyurl" in an iframe and monitor the parent window (the popup which IS from same origin) instead

PS: toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,width=430,height=220,left=500,top=100" should be the same as "width=430,height=220,left=500,top=100" but why not use a modal dialog with the URL in an iFrame?

Can't do anything iframe-y, it has to be a new window/tab.

Do you have classic CORS error logs in case of diff origin? Maybe you can setup web server to allow/* cross origin with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example

Is the buyurl from the same server as the script? Can you do iFrame in a new window/tab?

Okay @NikolaLukic, I changed the buyUrl to the current URL we were on, to check if there was a CORS-like error going on and now, I also got message and rawmessage (that could have just been because of the page though), but I also got pagehide and unload a second time, when I close the popup. So there's definitely something like that going on.
